# Multi-list iteration with default value in Python

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I'm running an experiment with python simulation, and need to create a list of input cases.

Each case is an instance taken from a list of list of parameters, For example:

```
heights = [100,110,120]
alphas = [0.1,0.01,0.001]
C = [0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9]
B = [1,2]
```

and the list of lists is:

```
params = [heights,alphas,C,B]
```

The original amount is bigger (~30x100) so it's not efficient to address each list directly.

Eventually each input case is a tuple/namedtuple/dictionary of one parameter from each category, for example:

```
instance = {'height':100, 'alpha':0.1,'C:0.1, 'B':1}
```

I would like to iterate the parameter space in order to create a list of instances - but here is **the catch**:

Instead of making a cartesian product of all of them, **per each parameter I want to iterate all the options, while the rest of categories are set to a default value (the first)**. For example:

```
params = [[1,2,3],[4,5][7,8]]
```

the expected set of instances (with no repeat) is:

> [(1,4,7),(2,4,7),(3,4,7),(1,5,7)(1,4,8)]

where **1** is the default of first index, *4* is the default of the second index and **7** is the default of the 3rd.

Making a cartesian product is quite easy with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product
params = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[7,8]]
list(product(*params))
```

> [(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8)]

then I can filter out unnecessary instances, but it sounds ineficient to generate them at first place. Is there any elegant way to build this iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
default = [par[0] for par in params]
instances = set()

for ii, pp in enumerate(params):
    for value in pp:
        new_instance = default[:ii] + [value] + default[ii + 1:]
        instances.add(tuple(new_instance))
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose another approach. Use [openTURNS](http://openturns.org). This python library is well developed and has some classes for defining a design of experiment which is said to have good properties in terms of space filling.

See here an example [LowDiscrepancySequence](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.LowDiscrepancySequence.html#openturns.LowDiscrepancySequence). Using this design you will be able to do statistical analysis, create models, etc. I am not related to them but they are well known in the field.

However, if you préfère you can stick with your method. To make it more pythonic I would build for that a generator expression or a list comprehension directly:

> ((I, j, k) for i, j, k in product(...))

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the 2nd and 3rd instance of each tuple in the final list, is the products from only the 2nd and third row of the initial array

```
a, *b = params
# a = [1, 2, 3]
# b = [[4, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Make a product out of all elements in b

```
import itertools

b = [x for x in itertools.product(*b)]
# b = [(4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 7), (5, 8)]
```

Now do a product of a with all the values of b

```
c = [(a, b, c) for a, (b, c) in itertools.product(a, b)]

# c = [(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8)]
```

**Overall shortened:**

```
import itertools

params = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5],
          [7,8]]

a, *b = params
f = itertools.product

c = [(a, b ,c) for a, (b, c) in f(a, f(*b))]
```

Comment: isn't it still first creates all the instances and then filters them out?

Comment: I looked at the last box you wrote and thought that was your desired output, oh well haha.